# Contextual styling of ReactJS styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm running into problems with Styled Components, and I'm not sure if it's a technical limitation, or if my mental model of how to use them is wrong.

In this example (I just wrote it quickly in Codepen, so disregard spelling mistakes) I have a component that is a username in a span. I want to be able to use that component anywhere, so it's styling is pretty minimal:

```
// From User.js    
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Username = styled.span`
  color: black;
`

const User = () => (
  <UserName>bla</Username>
);

export default User;
```

I want to be able to use this span in a different component, but in that case I want it's styling to be overridden in this context:

```
// From Userblock.js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import User from './user';

const UserWrapper = styled.div`
  // Some styles
`

const User = styled(User)`
  color: red; // Different color when displayed in a UserBlock
`

const UserBlock = () => (
  <UserWrapper>
    <User />
  </UserWrapper>
);

export default UserBlock;
```

From what I know, that's the way to set styling on a third party component (and that works elsewhere in my application), and it should work as far as I can tell, but I get nothing.

Also, going back to the mental model question - is this the way you're supposed to do it when you're using styled-components?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you wrap a normal React component with `styled(X)` you need to make sure to **attach the class that `styled-components` passes in**.

This means for your example, this will solve the issue:

```
const User = (props) => (
  <UserName className={props.className}>bla</Username>
);
```

When you override the styles of an existing component `styled-components` goes ahead, generates a class, injects it and passes it to the component. That means if you don't attach the class to anything you'll never see the styles though! (see [the documentation](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/docs/existing-css.md#styling-normal-react-components) for more information)

Comment: Thanks Max, that worked perfectly! I had actually found this old issue of yours (https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/8), but I guess I couldn't glean the answer from that ;P